# create an AlamoFire request from cURL

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to convert a groupMe alamofire post request below into appropriate Alamofire format in Swift. Particularly confused at converting `-d` part of the cURL.

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Family"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This is what I have :

```
let param = ["source_guid": "GUID", "text": "test message"] as Dictionary<String, String>

Alamofire.request(groupMePostUrl, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"]).responseJSON { response in
}
```

Running this, I am given the message `"text is required"` in debugger.

Comment: The `-d` <data> option is to `post` data using curl, While `-d` uses the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime-type, so try with update your `encoding` and `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 'name' in your body parameters. Probably you can do something like this:

```
let param = ["name": "Family", "text": "test message"]
        Alamofire.request("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups?token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:  ["Content-Type": "application/json"]).responseString { (responseStr) in
            print("response :\(responseStr)")

        }
```

Using this, you will get 201 code which means **Resource was created successfully**.